# Doorkeeper - Change Token Param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alexa-skills-kit, doorkeeper

This might just be a noob question, running rails 5 and doorkeeper gem.  Trying to figure out how I check if a access token is valid.

In my controller I have a `before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!` but every request I send I get:

```
Filter chain halted as :doorkeeper_authorize! rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized
```

I am guessing because the request is not what doorkeeper is expecting, I am getting the request from Amazon Alexa Service and thus the request body looks like this:

```
{
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "SessionId.1111",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.1111"
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {
      "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.some_id",
      "accesstoken": "some access token"
    }
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "EdwRequestId.1111",
    "intent": {
      "name": "helloworldintent",
      "slots": {}
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "timestamp": "2017-10-31T22:33:22Z"
  },
  "context": {
    "AudioPlayer": {
      "playerActivity": "IDLE"
    },
    "System": {
      "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.111"
      },
      "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.111",
        "accesstoken": "some access token"
      },
      "device": {
        "supportedInterfaces": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Is there a way to define what param the access token is in or am I doing this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you are actually using `doorkeeper` as intented? Doorkeeper allows you to expose the data in your Rails app using OAuth 2.0 protocol. It will handle the management of authorization and token management. Is that how you are using the doorkeeper gem.

Comment: So I have setup Doorkeeper to provide oauth tokens for my application, the oauth client is the Alexa app, which makes a request for auth grant token, then it makes requests to my API to get data(as above) with the token in the request.